# Edit time scheduled task on windows using php

Tags: php

I tried this command line in command prompt for edit time `SchTasks /Change /TN ReminderKontrak /ST 12:11 /RU EGGYS\Eggy` and the result is `Success` after I run cmd as administrator and enter the password..

and now I tried to implementation that to php code like this

```
shell_exec('SchTasks /Change /TN ReminderKontrak /ST 12:11 /RU EGGYS\Eggy');
```

and I tried add `/F` for force but it still not work like when I try add `/F` to delete task
but why the time not update and no error in browser?

Comment: PHP is not the right tool for the job. You shouldn't be executing commands that require administrator access in PHP

Comment: @Mike but it's not problem when I tried delete the task using `/F`